# Jupyter-notebook returns "module not found" for every single import, despite them being downloaded

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

For example, `import trackpy` returns the module not found error.I have already confirmed that trackpy has been downloaded *somewhere* on my computer, because attempting to install it again via `conda install -c soft-matter trackpy` will eventually return something to the effect of "all files already installed".  This seems to occur for every "external import" (numpy, scipy, matplotlib), i.e. one that was downloaded somewhere from the internet. This does not happen for "internal imports" (sys, os). I believe this is just a matter of jupyter not looking for the files in the correct place, but I don't know how to fix something like this.

Edit: Relevant info: I ran

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

which returns `'c:\\users\\reese\\miniconda3\\python.exe'`. In the pkgs folder for miniconda3, there are none of the imports that I want. However in `'c:\\users\\reese\\Anaconda\\pkgs'` are all the imports, trackpy and all else. Is there an easy way to make jupyter check here for imports? I already tried straight up copying the entire pkgs folder and pasting it in miniconda3's pkgs folder, but it did not work.

Comment: Show us what you get if you run `! conda list` and `pip list` on Jupyter notebook. Is `trackpy` on the output list?

Comment: I ran both of them and trackpy is not on either. Copy/pasting what they return is too long of a comment, is there a way to link longer text here?

Comment: check if the requirements is installed in the environment you are running jupyter notebook.
you can check using command pip freeze where you have ran the jupyter server.

Comment: Try this: change the python kernel that the Jupyter notebook runs on to other available one. Then do what I told you again.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but my jupter only shows one available kernel now, the one without all the packages. That environment only runs python2 though so I don't want to use it anyway, as that is not compatible with some of the other software I want to use.

Comment: You may need to install additional package:
`conda install nb_conda_kernels` and restart the Jupyter notebook server again.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I would propose.

Okay Solution:

Yes, you can add the path to your other packages with sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'PATH_TO_YOUR_OTHER_PACKAGES')

import Packages_of_another_path
```

By insert it at index zero, you ensure that your other packages get first priority in case there in another package with the same name.

Better Solution:(Recommendable)

Always use environments. E.g.

```
conda create —name your_env python=3.6 pip
conda activate your_env
conda install packages1 packages2
pip install package3
```

In this environment you can keep all you things together.
Everything you wish to use your packages, activate your environment and start hacking ;)

Comment: I attempted the first solution, and it did get rid of the 'module not found error', but now I am getting a different error on all imports,

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
I doubt that all such packages are broken, especially since I have used them before.

Comment: Also, I have tried many different imports (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, trackpy) and they all return the above error, mentioning numpy. Attempting to import astropy yields `ImportError: Numpy version 1.9.0 or later must be installed to use Astropy`, but I'm sure my numpy is up to date. To be sure I ran `pip3 install --upgrade numpy` and it was completed, but did not fix the problem.

Comment: You should avoid using pip as much as possible as conda is there to help you fix this issue. I do not like solution 1. As numpy import is from another path. You would need to conda upgrade numpy in that path.